# do I need every method in a class to be in the constructor for subclasses to inherit?

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, arguments

So, I have this class that I made, called fighter. I made it work for a minute. Then, I added this method:

```
private void roll(double block){
    block = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
}
```

This may sound stupid, but do I need to add it to the constructor to inherit the class? I want to do this with a subclass

```
public void attacked(int baseDamage){
  if (human.roll()==block){
     return "Nothing happens";
  }
  else{
     a = human.roll();
     human.health()-= a;
  }
  if (human.health > 0){
     System.out.println(health);
  }
```

}

So then, do I add roll() to the constructor or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: to answer your question: no. but i actually don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: Have you tried to use the extend keyword in order to share all methods and variables?

Comment: You can't "add methods to the constructor". But, maybe this answers your question already: private methods are not inherited and cannot be called from outside the class

Comment: actually whether is allowed to inherit your base class doesn't depend on your method but the `final` key word and the scope of your class

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code.  Your question doesn't make much sense.  Are you trying to call roll() from a derived class.  In that case you need to make roll() public.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well to answer the question

> do I need every method in a class to be in the constructor for
>   subclasses to inherit?

The answer is no. Just call what you want in the constructor. If you want to use a certain method from the subclass, then just make an instance of that class and call the method

```
Object object = new Object("your constructor info"); 
object.newMethod.
```

Is this what your asking ?

subclass inherits all the fields and methods of Super class and you can add the fields/variables and  methods to set it. Except for the constructor.

```
 /* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Fighter {

    // the Fighter class has three fields
    public int health;
    public int attack;
    public int speed;

    // the Fighter class has one constructor
    public Fighter(int health, int attack, int speed) {
        this.health = health;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.speed = speed;
    }
     // the Figher class has one method, so far...    
    public void roll(double block){
        block = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
    }
}

public class Attacker extends Fighter {

    // the Attacker subclass adds one field
    public int damage;

    // the Attacker subclass has one constructor
    public Attacker(int damage,
                        int health,
                        int attack,
                        int speed) {
        super(health, attack, speed);
        this.damage = damage;
    }   

    // the Attacker subclass adds one method
    public void attacked(int baseDamage){
        // Is human another class , then Fighter or did you mean Figher ? 
        if (super.roll()==block){
             return "Nothing happens";
        }
        else{
          int a = super.roll();
          human.health()-= damage;
        }
        if (super.health > 0){
           System.out.println(health);
        }  
    }
}
}
```

You could also invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword super.

```
super.roll();
```

This better help out ?

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question.

Comment: Hmmm, well I think this answer must have confused you. It is incorrect. You can access a superclass method from a subclass method, if it is protected or public... No instantiation involved.

Comment: Yeah that's true if you are calling super methods from the sub class.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the `extend` keyword in the subclass, and make the `void` method, `attacked`, into a separate class. Now they both will share the exact same methods, and you can still return things to each other.

Another way you can tackle this issue is by again, making those two methods into two separate classes, and nest the subclass underneath the superclass just above the last bracket. If this is part of a larger code you can nest multiple sequences together, or just put multiple methods together. You don't need to add it to the constructor though, the above two reasons were just things you could try which would give you the same answer.

*Because you are returning something you don't need to add that method to the constructor!*

Comment: Thanks. Well, that tells me something about whats wrong with my subclass. Now I know that that isn't the problem, I will now proceed to try and find out what the problem actually is with my subclass.

Comment: Glad I could help. I could help you find the problem with the subclass, just tell me what the goal of this code is and I will try and find as many different ways to solve the problem as possible!